# Child activity not being invoked anymore after finish()

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

My scenario is simple: I have a MainActivity that calls CategoryActivity that lists all my Categories. In this CategoryActivity, I have a button to add a new Category. When user clicks on this button, RegisterCategoryActivity is called and the user fills the fields and then save it. After saving it, I'm calling finish() on RegisterCategoryActivity but the problem is that if I try to add a new Category again, RegisterCategoryActivity is not invoked anymore BUT if I go back to my MainActivity -> CategoryActivity and then click on the button, it works ok. What am I missing here?

**CategoryActivity**

```
public class CategoryActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_categories);       
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    new LoadCategories().execute(); // load categories from DB
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_category, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_activity_category:
            Intent registerCategoryActivity = new Intent(CategoryActivity.this, RegisterCategoryActivity.class);
            registerCategoryActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            startActivity(registerCategoryActivity);
        return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**RegisterCategoryActivity**

```
public class RegisterCategoryActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_category);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();           
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_save, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_save:
            validateFields();
        return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/** Inner class for implementing progress bar before fetching data **/
private class RegisterCategory extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> 
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
        int result;
        ...
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result)
    {
        ...

        finish();
    }
}
```

}

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
        android:name="com.app.RegisterCategoryActivity"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_categories"
        android:label="@string/registerCategory"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
    </activity>

<activity
        android:name="com.app.CategoryActivity"            
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_categories"
        android:label="@string/categories">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>  
    </activity>
```

Comment: I can see no problem with the code you have posted. Can you provide the missing parts?

Comment: What is the purpose of using this flag: FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT  when ur not load the activity from the stack and what is ur min sdk support? There are some issues with the applied flag and raised as bugs https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64103 & https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3416

Comment: min sdk = 8. I'm using this flag to prevent this case: if user goes to RegisterCategoryActivity and press home button and then he comes back to my app, he should be able to press the back button and go to CategoryActivity

Comment: You don't need `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` to get the behaviour you just described. That behaviour is the default behaviour.

Comment: I've set it to all activities in my app because a time ago I was having the problem I mentioned: when I pressed home button and opened my app again, if I pressed back button it returned me to the home screen and not to the previous activity. You're telling me that this won't happen if I remove this flag from my activities?